# Adding Sparkle framework in Xcode 4

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, sparkle

I'm totally stuck in a operation that might be really simple...adding Sparkle to a project created in Xcode 4. 
I did these operations :

- Added Sparkle.framework to my project (drag&drop)
- Added to "link Binary With Libraries" but it generated this error:

  dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
    Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-esurnmkwvxcgcxbbrdgsobkoimfv/Build/Products/Release/Myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp

  Reason: image not found
- Removed to "link Binary With Libraries"
- Added to "Copy Bundle Resources"
- Add an instance on SUUpdater to mainMenu.xib
- Did every config step required (create the private Key, upload file and rss etc..)

When i launch my application i get a warning :

```
Unknown class 'SUUpdater', using 'NSObject' instead. Encountered in Interface Builder file at path /Users/...etcetcetc
```

And obviously due to this warning the updater never starts. What I missed?

Comment: What was the error when you added the link step? You'll need that, because else the unarchiver doesn't know what to do with a SUUpdater object.

Comment: @phil I edited my answer with details about the error

Comment: Are you sure that your version of Sparkle is built for all architectures? What does lipo -info <path to>/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to import the Sparkle framework into the header file for your class:

```
#import <Sparkle/Sparkle.h>

@implementation YourClass : NSObject
{

}
```

This isn't mentioned in your question as one of the steps you've taken, hence I'm assuming it hasn't been done.

Comment: I needed to do this in a Cocoa/Applescript project recently — note that the file to add the import line to would be `main.m` under ‘Supporting Files’.